# android Billing Library 5.0 - misunderstanding some features

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

Google has released Billing Library 5.0 with the new way to deal with subscriptions, but I had some misunderstanding while researching:

1. Is it true that I really can't purchase another base plan or offer of a currently active subscription? The strange thing is that, when creating a base plan, Google offers you this option:
   [image]
   Looks like you should be able to crossgrade between base plans or offers within the same product.
   But when I purchased the product, Google didn't let me buy another offer from the same product until the subscription was canceled. And when I canceled the subscription myself, I could purchase another offer right away, without waiting for canceled subscription to actually finish.
2. I was pretty surprised that I received offers with "upgrade" eligibility criteria even when I didn't have the subscription, that I've chosen in "current subscription" field, active. I thought there is a problem with cache, since I could receive newly created offers only several hours after creating, but I could even purchase those "upgrade" offers despite didn't have corresponding subscription active.

Am I missing something? Could you please explain to me how these things should really work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

#1 I was also looking for the same, but found no relevant documentation. Just got it working while following the API. For it to work, we also need to provide old purchase token. The following snippet should be self-explanatory: -

```
val productDetail: ProductDetails = //product details for new subscription
val offerToken: String = //offer token for new subscription
val purchaseToken: String? = //purchase token of ongoing subscription
val productDetailsParamsList = listOf(
    BillingFlowParams.ProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductDetails(productDetail)
        .setOfferToken(offerToken)
        .build()
)
val billingFlowParamsBuilder = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
    .setProductDetailsParamsList(productDetailsParamsList)
purchaseToken?.let {
    billingFlowParamsBuilder.setSubscriptionUpdateParams(
        SubscriptionUpdateParams.newBuilder()
            .setOldPurchaseToken(purchaseToken)
            .setReplaceProrationMode(BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.IMMEDIATE_WITHOUT_PRORATION)
            .build()
    )
}
model.client.launchBillingFlow(this, billingFlowParamsBuilder.build())
```

I'm not sure about #2 (I don't even need that).